# How do I use fingerprint-gui's polkit agent with GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome-shell, polkit

I'm using Arch Linux, and have installed `fingerprint-gui` from AUR. It detected the sensor after I added myself to the `plugdev` and `scanner` groups. After prepending the following to `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`:

```
auth      sufficient pam_fingerprint-gui.so
```

I can authenticate to `sudo`, LightDM, GNOME Screensaver, etc. with it.

The problem is with applications using Polkit. `fingerprint-gui` comes with its own Polkit authentication agent (`/usr/lib/fingerprint-gui/fingerprint-polkit-agent`, supposed to be autostarted by `/etc/xdg/autostart/fingerprint-polkit-agent.desktop`). However, it does not start:

```
$ pgrep polkit -fa
2247 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug
$ /usr/lib/fingerprint-gui/fingerprint-polkit-agent -d
New PolkitAgentListener  0x1b5f700 
Adding new listener  PolkitQt1::Agent::Listener(0x7ffecc222550) for  0x1b5f700 

** (fingerprint-polkit-agent:2951): WARNING **: Unable to register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication agent already exists for the given subject
"Cannot register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication agent already exists for the given subject" 
Destroying listener
Removing listener  PolkitQt1::Agent::Listener(0x7ffecc222550)
```

Apparently there's an agent already running. [The Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fingerprint-gui) suggests removing the following files from `/etc/xdg/autostart` if GNOME or KDE is installed:

```
polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop
polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1.desktop
```

I use GNOME Shell, but I don't have `polkit-gnome` installed (and hence I don't have these files). However, it seems GNOME Shell has its own Polkit agent:

```
$ locate polkit | grep agent                             
/etc/xdg/autostart/fingerprint-polkit-agent.desktop
...
/usr/lib/libpolkit-agent-1.so
/usr/lib/libpolkit-agent-1.so.0
/usr/lib/libpolkit-agent-1.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/libpolkit-qt-agent-1.so
/usr/lib/libpolkit-qt-agent-1.so.1
/usr/lib/libpolkit-qt-agent-1.so.1.112.0
...
$ lsof /usr/lib/libpolkit-agent-1.so.0.0.0
COMMAND   PID    USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
gnome-she 757    muru mem    REG  259,0    40200 289001 /usr/lib/libpolkit-agent-1.so.0.0.0
```

What can I do to use `fingerprint-gui`'s Polkit agent with GNOME Shell?

```
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.18.1
```

Answer (score 2):

After dithering a bit, I replaced `gnome-session` with a wrapper:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/gnome-session
#! /bin/sh

/usr/lib/fingerprint-gui/fingerprint-polkit-agent -d &
exec /usr/bin/gnome-session "$@"
```

The `fingerprint-gui` Polkit agent is horribly ugly, though:

[image]